# Проблема при кодировании данных

Tags: c++

```
unsigned char *writeInt(int v)
{
    static unsigned char lol[4];
    lol[0] = (((v >> 24) & 0xFF));
    lol[1] = (((v >> 16) & 0xFF));
    lol[2] = (((v >>  8) & 0xFF));
    lol[3] = (((v      ) & 0xFF));
    return lol;
}
int readInt(unsigned char i[])
{
    return (
            ((i[0] << 24) & 0xFF) |
            ((i[1] << 16) & 0xFF) |
            ((i[2] <<  8) & 0xFF) |
             (i[3]        & 0xFF));
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << readInt(writeInt(10)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Таким образом кодирую int, но при декоде большие числа не корректно отображаются. Пример в данном случае возвращает 10, но возьму число 10000 мне возвращает 16.

Comment: Зачем вы при декоде коньюктите? Вы сдвигаете и сразу обнуляете всё, остаётся только то, что было в i[3]

Comment: Уберите `&0xFF` из `readInt` - подумайте сами, вы же ими все портите!